# Start a Web page from a MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

.net core 2.0

I have a HomeController with Views, ect.  From a same/different controller that has issued a GET to another web site, I need to "start/redirect" to my HomeController.  Maybe a bit hard to explain but I'm trying to simulate an Oauth flow where I need to  check to see if a user is logged on and if not redirect the user's browser to my signon page.  Seems like it ought to be simple out I'm not having any luck.  So if I have the code below, can I start up a new browser session with my logon page:

```
    public IActionResult Logon()
    {
        return View();
    }

    HttpGet("auth")]
    public void Get(string client_id, string redirect_uri, string state,  string scope, string response_type)
    {

        if(!isloggedOn)
        {
            LocalRedirectPermanent("Logon");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post how are you calling this Get method?

Comment: I have tried virtually all of the IActionResult redirects.  Looking for a browser page to open.  But it just runs with no visible account..  I'm beginning to think I'm approaching it wrong.  I use POSTMAN to do a localhost:5000/auth?client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE_STRING&scope=REQUESTED_SCOPES&response_type=code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Postman will not redirect to a http URL.  You have to be able to get the redirect on https.  Buried not too deep in the documentation.